# Re enable mouse wheel scroll in Firefox

Tags: firefox, scroll

I'm using those:

```
body{ -ms-overflow-style: none;} /* for ie hiding scroll bar */

body::-webkit-scrollbar{display:none;} /* chrome hiding scroll bar*/

body{overflow:-moz-scrollbars-none;}/* hides the scroll bar for Firefox */
```

to hide the default browser scrollbars, it is all fancy & dandy for chromie & IE ( yay ! ), 

although in Firefox I'm loosing the ability to scroll with mouse scroll,
 what is weird is beside that I can scroll, but only with Up/Down arrows or pageUp/pageDown keys. 

Is there something that I can do to re-enable scrolling with mouse wheel in Firefox?


In the post that I've found all of those neat lines of code the author said that we need to implement this as well for Firefox:

```
$(function() { 
jQuery.scrollSpeed(100, 800);
}); // for page scrolling
```

But it does not work for me, or maybe I'm doing sth wrong.

Thx for stopping by o/

Comment: "-moz-scrollbars-none" appears to be an alias for "hidden", and "-moz-scrollbars-none" itself is apparently deprecated. So you might want to use "hidden" instead. This doesn't solve the problem though.

Comment: hmm.. it is so weird though, why would someone remove m.wheel scrolling and leave option to scroll with keyboard keys, eh

Comment: Yeah I don't really see the rationale either, but I also couldn't find any way to work around it when I checked the firefox source.